# Passing current page id to a link_to (Ruby/ Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, link-to

Apologies if this seems a bit vague.

Basically I have a page which loads content based on id. I'm trying to put links withing it like this

```
<%= link_to 'mypage', {:action => 'mypageload', :id => '1'},{:class=>'mypages'}%>
```

What I'd like to do is pass the id of the current page into this link.

So something like

```
:id => 'params[:id]'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the single quotes: `:id => params[:id]`

Comment: ha. I wasn't far off i see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the params variable in the views. In your example you put the params inside quotes making it a string. Just leave those out and you should be fine, like this:

```
<%= link_to 'mypage', {:action => 'mypageload', :id => params[:id]},{:class=>'mypages'}%>
```